# cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an ArrayList that contains an object of another class, a name, and turn. something similar to the python's dictionary.

```
self.user1 = {"user":user1,"name":empty,"turn":empty}
```

so I made a class that has the 3 values.

```
class User{
public userInterface user1;
String name;
String turn;

public User(UserInterface user1,String name,String turn) {
    this.user1=user1;
    this.name=name;
    this.turn=turn;
}}
```

and I'm trying to call it in the constructor of main class as following:

```
public class MainClassConstructon{
ArrayList<User> user1;
ArrayList<User> user2;

MainClassConstructon(UserInterface user1 ,UserInterface user2){
     this.user1 = new ArrayList<>(new User(user1,empty, empty));
     this.user2 = new ArrayList<>(new User(user2,empty, empty));
```

but it raises an error saying that: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>.

Comment: Try `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new User(user1,empty, empty)));`.

Comment: where does the `empty` come fromin `MainClassConstructon`?
@lexicore: this would create a `ArrayList<List<User>>`...

Comment: Are these lists going to grow at all?  If not, use `Collections.singletonList`.  If they are going to grow, then create them empty first, then add the element.

Comment: You don't need the lists it looks like, just use fields of type `User`.

Comment: @EmersonCod How so? `ArrayList` has a `(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor.

Comment: The argument is either initial capacity or a collection. You can not be passing the object you want to store in it, It should be `ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(new User(....));`

Comment: @lexicore - of course - you are right. my bad....

Answer (score 8):

ArrayList has three constructors:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
public ArrayList()
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

`User` is neither an `int` nor a `Collection`, and you're passing an argument so the middle constructor doesn't apply either.

But that's beside the point, your goal is to create a single list of users, so instead of doing what you're currently doing, you need to use only a single list, and simply add your users:

```
public class MainClassConstructon{
  List<User> users; // Or ArrayList, doesn't really matter

  MainClassConstructon(UserInterface user1 ,UserInterface user2){
    users = new ArrayList<>(); // Diamond syntax, requires Java 7+
    users.add(new User(user1, "", ""));
    users.add(new User(user2, "", ""));
  }
}
```

Comment: or `users = Arrays.asList(new User(user1, "", ""), new User(user2, "", ""));`

Comment: A good alternative indeed, or one could choose `LinkedList` instead, or perhaps an immutable implementation depending on the needs.

It's good to keep in mind though, that `Arrays.asList` returns an implementation of `List` that is defined as inner class in `Arrays` (conveniently also called `ArrayList`)

Comment: I assume that the OP doesn't want to add more users once the constructor is finished. So `Arrays.asList()` should work as it is `imutable-like`

Comment: Good way of phrasing it - the implementation supports `set` but not `add`

Answer (score 2):

well i made it like this:

```
this.user1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new User(user1,empty, empty)));
```

and was able to access it by:

```
t.user1.get(0).name="bla bla";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
public class MainClassConstructon {
    ArrayList<User> user1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<User> user2 = new ArrayList<>();

    MainClassConstructon(UserInterface user1, UserInterface user2) {
        this.user1.add(new User(user1, "", ""));
        this.user2.add(new User(user2, "", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a java developer but i suggest you try and look on Arraylist api.

Here is what i found online, sry if it doesn't help :)

```
import java.util.*; 
public class ArrayListDemo { public static void main(String args[]) { 
// create an array list 
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); 
System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size()); 
// add elements to the array list 
al.add("C"); 
al.add("A"); 
al.add("E"); 
al.add("B"); 
al.add("D"); 
al.add("F"); 
al.add(1, "A2"); 
System.out.println("Size of al after additions: " + al.size());

 // display the array list System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);

 // Remove elements from the array list al.remove("F");
al.remove(2); 
System.out.println("Size of al after deletions: " + al.size());
 System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al); 
}
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Also that it's just copied from somewhere without any link to its sourcecode makes this just a bad answer